# Understanding with custom jQuery slider next button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div with 3 divs inside it each of the inner divs have a class of content and one has a class of current. I was trying to show only one .content at a time and just have a next button that hides the div and removes the .current class and adds it to the next one. It all works fine but when I get to the end of the divs. I want it to just circle back to the first one. The following code doesn't do that. The first one shows but the next button stops working after that:

js:

```
var $ = jQuery

$( document ).ready( function() {


  $('#next').click(function(){

  var item = $('.content.current');
  item.removeClass('current');
  item.slideUp();
  item.next().addClass('current');
  if(item.next().length == 0) {

    $('.content').first().slideDown().addClass('current').end();

  }
  })
})
```

HTML:

```
<div id="holder">
        <a class="btn btn-warning next" id="next">next</a>
        <div class="wrap">

        <div class="content current">

        <div id="header"><h3>Basic</h3></div>

        <ul>
          <li>Unlimited Bandwidth</li>
          <li>Unlimited Diskspace</li>
          <li>10 Email Accounts</li>          
          <li>24/7 Support!</li>
          <li>$4/month</li>
          <li><a class="btn btn-success">Order Now!</a></li>
        </ul>

        </div>
        <!-- .content -->

        <div class="content">

        <div id="header"><h3>Professional</h3></div>

        <ul>
          <li>Unlimited Bandwidth</li>
          <li>Unlimited Diskspace</li>
          <li>10 Email Accounts</li>          
          <li>24/7 Support!</li>
          <li><a class="btn btn-success">Order Now!</a></li>
        </ul>

        </div>
        <!-- .content -->

        <div class="content">

        <div id="header"><h3>St. Joseph</h3></div>

        <ul>
          <li>Unlimited Bandwidth</li>
          <li>Unlimited Diskspace</li>
          <li>10 Email Accounts</li>          
          <li>24/7 Support!</li>
          <li><a class="btn btn-success">Order Now!</a></li>
        </ul>

        </div>
        <!-- .content -->



        </div>
        <!-- .wrap -->

      </div>
      <!-- holder -->
```

Answer (score 0):

What your  `$('.content').first().slideDown().addClass('current').end();` does is it'll show the first element and add the `current` class to it. Change your script to this

```
var $ = jQuery
$( document ).ready( function() {
  $('#next').click(function(){
  var item = $('.content.current');
  item.removeClass('current');
  item.slideUp();
  item.next().addClass('current');
  if(item.next().length == 0) {
    $('.content').slideDown();
    $('.content').first().addClass('current');
  }
  });
});
```

and it will work. Here is a example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m5ydgzLa/). Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var $ = jQuery

$( document ).ready( function() {


    var i = 1;

    $('#next').click(function(){

        ++i;

        $('.content.current').removeClass("current").slideUp();
        $(".content:nth-child("+i+")").addClass("current").slideDown();

        if(i == 3) i=0;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="holder">
        <a class="btn btn-warning next" id="next">next</a>
    <div class="wrap">

        <div class="content current">

        <div id="header"><h3>Basic</h3></div>

        <ul>
          <li>Unlimited Bandwidth</li>
          <li>Unlimited Diskspace</li>
          <li>10 Email Accounts</li>          
          <li>24/7 Support!</li>
          <li>$4/month</li>
          <li><a class="btn btn-success">Order Now!</a></li>
        </ul>

        </div>
        <!-- .content -->

        <div class="content">

        <div id="header"><h3>Professional</h3></div>

        <ul>
          <li>Unlimited Bandwidth</li>
          <li>Unlimited Diskspace</li>
          <li>10 Email Accounts</li>          
          <li>24/7 Support!</li>
          <li><a class="btn btn-success">Order Now!</a></li>
        </ul>

        </div>
        <!-- .content -->

        <div class="content">

        <div id="header"><h3>St. Joseph</h3></div>

        <ul>
          <li>Unlimited Bandwidth</li>
          <li>Unlimited Diskspace</li>
          <li>10 Email Accounts</li>          
          <li>24/7 Support!</li>
          <li><a class="btn btn-success">Order Now!</a></li>
        </ul>

        </div>
        <!-- .content -->

    </div>
        <!-- .wrap -->

</div>
      <!-- holder -->
```

It's very easy if you insist to do it with JS :

```
$( document ).ready( function() {

    var i = 1;

    $('#next').click(function(){

        ++i;

        $('.content.current').removeClass("current").slideUp();
        $(".content:nth-child("+i+")").addClass("current");

        if(i == 3) i=0;
    })
})
```

but better option is `BOOTSTRAP` which I guess you are using.

you can find it here: [Collapse Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion)